# IQueryable in Entity Framework Core to set entity property equal to count of rows on other entity (table)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an entity that has its own log table (separate entity). I need to return my entity which has a property for the count of rows on the log entity and I'd like to do it all with one database trip. I've tried using the `Select()` method on `IQueryable` to set the property value but that is forcing me to call `AsEnumerable()` first and I have another custom extension method off of `IQueryable` later down the chain that I can't change.

How can I accomplish this?

Here's the `AsEnumerable()` method that works for getting a collection, but won't work for my case:

```
_context
        .Include(x => x.IrrelevantToMyProblemEntity)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select( x =>
        {
            x.LogCount = _context.LogEntity.Count();
            return x;
        }
    );
```

Comment: Who/what is forcing you to use `AsEnumerable()`? What is the problem/error message you get when you try it without? In case you get an error message, please post the complete error message. If possible provide a [mcve], which shows what tables/entities you have, the example input you have and the desired output you want.

Comment: w/o the AsEnumerable I get this error: "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree.  An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator"

Comment: Select is for reading not for writing. You can mutate in an enumerable select, as you have discovered, but even then it should usually be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use group  if you want to commutative sets while using  aggregate function

```
   group x by x.IrrelevantToMyProblemEntityinto g
   select new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```